# Filtering a List of Objects by multiple Object Attributes

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am building a Google App Engine application (Python 2.7) using the NDB API.  I am new to python development and have a feeling this is a question that has been answered before, but I have been unable to find, through my search efforts, something resembling this problem/solution. I decided to pose my question here.

I have a Document model class that I need to query and get the most "current" Documents.  Specifically, I want to get a list of document objects(entities) with distinct document names and whose `expiration` date (a `datetime.date` object) is the greatest value.

For example, a query of documents in descending order by expiration date such as:

```
documents = Document.query().order(-Document.expiration).fetch()
```

returns:

```
[{"name": "DocumentC", "expiration": datetime.date(2015, 3, 1)},
 {"name": "DocumentA", "expiration": datetime.date(2014, 4, 1)},
 {"name": "DocumentB", "expiration": datetime.date(2014, 2, 15)},
 {"name": "DocumentA", "expiration": datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)}]
```

Based on these query results, I want to remove the second (older) occurrence of "DocumentA" and get something like this:

```
[{"name": "DocumentC", "expiration": datetime.date(2015, 3, 1)},
 {"name": "DocumentA", "expiration": datetime.date(2014, 4, 1)},
 {"name": "DocumentB", "expiration": datetime.date(2014, 2, 15)}]
```

My solution is:

```
def current_docs(docs):
    output = []
    for d in docs:
        if not any(o['name'] == d['name'] for o in output):
            output.append(d)
    return output

cd = current_docs(documents)
# returns:
# [{'expiration': datetime.date(2015, 3, 1), 'name': 'DocumentC'},
# {'expiration': datetime.date(2014, 4, 1), 'name': 'DocumentA'},
# {'expiration': datetime.date(2014, 2, 15), 'name': 'DocumentB'}]
```

This seems to give me the result I expect, but:

1. Is there a better way to filter the original query to get the results I want from the start?
2. If not, is there a better, more efficient approach than my solution?

Comment: I don't know how to improve the original query, but @2: I would reverse the list and then add the elements to a dictionary using 'name' as key, so duplicate entries will be overwritten by the most recent ones.

Comment: Why do you allow duplicate document names ?

Comment: @TimHoffman I probably should have used `category` or `type` instead of `name`.  So, there could be multiple documents with the same category/type.  Ultimately, then, I want a list of distinct document entities based on their `document.name` (aka category/type).  However, in making the distinction between objects with the same name the deciding factor is their expiration dates.  The code should select the entity with the greatest expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach at your second question:

```
def current_docs(docs):
  tmp = {}
  output = []
  for d in docs:
    if d['name'] in tmp:
      continue
    tmp[d['name']] = 1
    output.append(d)
  return output
```

Keep a dictionary of already added names and add only those that have not yet been added. Don't know anything about Google App Engine though :)

Comment: This does not remove the "older" object with matching `name` attribute (in this example, "DocumentA"). It simply returns the original query results.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed. `pass` has to be `continue` of course. Edited answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provided your data meets the restrictions noted in the documentation, you should be able to use a projection query and `group_by=["name"]` and `distinct=True` to accomplish this.

- Docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection

Alternatively, I'd recommend saving data into a precomputed table that contains only unique document names and the latest data/status for it. You incur additional cost at write time, but you get fast reads and don't have to rely on unfiltered data set fitting into the instance memory, which is required if you intend to filter at run time.